# How to protect a template locking it to a url

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

I'm building a costum wp theme that must be exclusive for a domain URL, what I want to do is lock the theme there, how can this be done ? I was thinking using PHP to check for the URL before including, lets say, the footer.php, and have that part of the code incripted, what do you think? is there a easier way?

What would that require? Looking at the server vars request? I guess I can google that, your opinion on the logic/algorithm would be very appreciated.

Warning, I'm not an advance coder.

Answer (score 1):

Since it´s PHP and open source, you can´t. And even if you do, it´s possible to edit the source and remove the limitations.

The best thing you can do is to encrypt a part of source code with a license file. But even that way, this will make some parts of your theme impossible to change, and the base funcionality can skip the license check. A dead end.

I recommend you to take a look at a commercial template, andthe business model theme makers use to make it profitable.

You can find more, learning with other developers, try http://themeforest.net/

Comment: well yeas I know, but the customers that would get access to this template are not savy enough to remove those limitations, I just want to encrypt a part of the template to check if it is installed on a certain domain, and encrypt that part, then for isntace, that part is responsible to load the footer, if the theme is not on the right domain, it would load the footer, does generating on screen errors, is this possible?

Comment: well, if clients are so dumb to edit a php file and replace a include or a function there you go. You just need to encrypt a part of the template, like functions.php, and use many functions defined in this file in your template. You can use Zend Guard, IonCube Loader or NuSphere Nu-Coder. The server needs support to decode it.